Dimmer circuit for LED brightness control
I have a circuit using 555 timer with 2 tact switches to increase and decrease the brightness of LED, but what I need is to store the last state of circuit whether it is on/ off and also automatically need to turn if the push button is not pressed for 3 minutes. I know it has to be done with microcontroller. But I don't know how to add that with my circuit. Kindly advise.

Too broad. You can simply remove everything you have now and make a MCU to control the LED. There must be millions of tutorials how to use LED with MCU.

If the entire circuit is about just an LED and two tact switches, one marked UP and one marked DOWN, then an MCU is the overwhelmingly right answer to the problem. If you are far behind on the learning curve, then the best answer is to "get started soon." Because, sooner or later, you will need to do something like this again. You may as well pay the piper now and get it over with. I have a complete tutorial (12 lessons, MSP430) that get you up to the point where an LED varies in brightness according to how people perceive it (geometric changes in duty.) I could post a link.

But if there are more circuit functions involved then you should disclose those, as well. Finally, if you want to do so, you could just buy a square-loop core and apply a few wires and a specialized pulsing circuit to change its state. I can refer you to youtube videos as well as a book on Amazon to move you along in that direction. It's a blast to the past when core memory was a thing. And one bit of core memory isn't that hard to do with an analog circuit. But it is unusual.

Hi peri blepsis,, could you please post a reference link which could be helpful

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

You can get some idea from here: https://how2electronics.com/light-dimmer-circuit-using-555-timer-ic-mosfet/

@Nandv Try core memory, lesson 1 to start out. Then watch the rest. And look up his book Magnetic Core Memory Decoded by J S Walker. (I purchased a copy, myself.)
